# If I develop an app FROM Microsoft in C++ Targeting Linux, are Miscrosft library good?

Tags: c++, g++, embedded-linux, libraries

The situation is this:

I do not have access to a machine running on `Linux`, just a little embedded platform where I cannot install any IDE (which is in LINUX and is my target), so I got to develop the app **from** my `Microsoft` PC.

The question is: should I use Microsoft libraries? Because I am developing in a `Microsoft environment`, or should I use Linux libraries? Because my `target is Linux`?

Comment: No access to Linux? that is the least of your problems, you can install Linux in a virtual machine (e.g. VirtualBox) in your Windows among many other options.

Comment: What are "microsoft libraries"? In general, you use the libraries compatible with your target, i.e. Linux in this case.

Comment: @alfC wouldn't it be very slow? I mean, I got to work with an 8GB Ram PC and its memory free space is a joke. If I install and run a virtual machine, wouldn't my PC "explode"?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I meant Microsoft compatible Libraries. Anyway, you are saying to use Linux libraries, do you confirm it? anyway, thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Yes, most probably you only care about linux compatibility.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks again, just one more thing. Would although Visual Studio run on my Microsoft PC, or would I have to always test it on the chip (which runs on Linux)? because of the libraries not being compatible with Microsoft.

Comment: @AlessandroCinque, you can install a lean version of linux, requiring 1GB RAM or less. computers don't explode these days.

Comment: Some libraries are compatible with several compilers/OSes. If yours are not compatible with Visual Studio, you can't use it. You might have some luck with https://www.msys2.org/ or Cygwin, which offers greater linux compatiblity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications targeting Windows do not work out-of-the-box in a Linux system (see some discussion here https://superuser.com/a/209736).

You could, however, use a Linux guest from the Windows host, through a virtual machine or [even docker](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/windows-ubuntu-hyperv-containers#1-overview).

Also, your "*little chip* target on which you cannot install an IDE" sounds like an embedded platform. Make sure the architecture on the target is the same as your windows pc x86-64 (intel). Many embedded platforms have a different architecture (e.g., ARM's aarch64). In this case, make sure to use an appropriate [cross-compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) that will create code for the target.

Comment: Yes, indeed we are talking about an embedded system.